# How to work with ranges like 1930-31, 1945-46 in a column of a data frame in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm practicing some statistical analysis on a data frame of la liga record, in which i'm trying to find teams that started playing between 1930-1980. But there are few rows that have dates like 1941-42, 1975-76. I have the dataset like this

I have tried this, but this results in error

```
dfnew = df[(df['Debut']>1930) & (df['Debut']<1980)]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZPr.png)

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: copy paste a sample of the dataframe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get better answers on your question, I recommend you add some example dataframe and some expected output so we can visually see what you want to do. Find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this would be to use [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) and slice the first 4 characters, then cast to `int`:

```
df['Debut'] = df['Debut'].astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)
```

Then filter with [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and boolean indexing:

```
df_new = df[df['Debut'].between(1930, 1980)]
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think OP need all years

Comment: this gives an error-
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1931-32'

Comment: that string has 7 characters, are you doing the slicing step... `.str[:4]`  ?

Comment: thanx, it works perfectly. I made a typing error in slicing step!!

Answer (score 0):

After slicing, the teams who have played their debut matches between given dates can be found in boolean form, ie. if team had played between 1930-80, will show `True` else `False`.

```
s=pd.Series([pd.read_csv('Laliga.csv')])

s=Laliga['Debut'].astype(str).str[:4].astype('int', copy=True, errors= 'ignore')

s.between(1930, 1980)
```